# Dark Liferay Theme - Customize Alloy popups

Tags: css, liferay, liferay-theme, alloy-ui

I have developed a dark Liferay theme (dark background, white font). But now I have a problem, because the Alloy Popups and Overlays are light (white background, and now also white font).

Is there a nice way to override the AUI-* css classes in a theme? Because the classes are not included in the _unstyled Theme.

Or can the AUI classes be customized for a portal instance only?

Thanks!

Here is the screenshot:

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not available in _unstyled but it is in _styled, have a look at /portal-trunk/portal-web/docroot/html/themes/_styled/css folder and you will get all css for .aui.

You can take this and override in your custom.css as the custom.css of your developed theme will be loaded at last and thus it will have first priority for the loading.

Hope this helps.